# how to find the entry of run function in main.go?

Tags: go

i am not a GO programmer, when i read the code of GO,i find such code

```
func main() {
  ......
        run(options)
}
```

and i am very confused the function run will run what? anyone can help?

Comment: Please read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) for such basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be fair, the code you posted will produce the following:

```
prog.go:4:3: syntax error: unexpected ..., expecting }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/HMv-FydjKWf

However, in a more complete example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Options struct {
    Enabled bool
}

func run(opts Options) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", opts)
}

func main() {
    opts := Options{
        Enabled: true,
    }

    run(opts)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-bHPWWxi-wm

The basics of what's occurring, is Go starts the execution of your program from the `main` func. In this case, you're calling the function `run`, and providing it some runtime options that you decided (such as my case, of `Enabled` being `true` for no reason).

I suggest taking a look at https://tour.golang.org/ to get acquainted with the language. Nothing particularly unique is happening in Go, minus a few syntactical choices.

Go is *very* obvious with its approach to code. To that end, nothing is magic, and there is a very simple programming explanation to what's happening. Not sure what `run` does? Go to that function and check it out! Once you figure out the syntax, you'll be surprised how readable things are.

**+Edit**: One final point I'll make, is that if you're having difficulty just *finding* `func run()`, just "Find in directory" or whatever your editor of choice calls it. The function will be in a file in the same folder. I also recommend checking out some Go packages for various editors (VS Code, Sublime, Atom, whatever), so  you can just click-through to the location of the function. These little time savers help, and basically just "Find in directory" for you.

Comment: but i do not see any run function in main.go

Comment: Check another file in the same folder, as I mentioned. Packages can use any method within them, regardless of file.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a function called `run` defined and available in the file scope. Functions are available in the file scope if:

- The function is defined in the file (obviously)
- The function is defined in another file in the same directory (same package)
- The function is defined in a package that is imported into scope using the dot syntax for importing

  ```
  import . "anotherpackage"
  ```

  If that package exports a function, it will be available in the current file.

  In your example code, the function `run` is lowercase. Since packages in Go only export functions that start with an uppercase, this scenario is not likely.